# Share screen to multiple users on lync?

Tags: lync

Is it possible to share my screen with multiple users on lync ? I'm able to do this one-on-one but I can't initiate a screen share with 2+ people. Any suggestions/reasons ?

Comment: you can share screen with multiple people by starting a meeting.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/lync-help/share-your-desktop-or-programs-in-a-lync-meeting-HA102809770.aspx?CTT=1

Comment: What version of Lync are you using?

Comment: @RyanGates I'm using Lync 2013 (v 15.0.4481) ..It was an internal issue with our companies intranet. Issue resolved re-installing lync

Comment: If you were able to resolve the issue, can you please post the solution as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply re-installing lync server should resolve the issue of not seeing the multiple users on lync. This worked for us and we made no further changes.